# HTML Options from SQL Database

Tags: php, html, database, html-datalist

I have a HTML `DataList` input box, and I would like to have the options in the `DataList` to be things from my `SQL` database. I have been trying to make this work, but for some reason I cant. Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include_once 'connect.php';

    $sql="select * FROM table";

?>
<form>
<input list="list" name="name">
  <datalist id="datalist">

  <?php 
      foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
         echo "<option value="$row[name]"/>";
      }

   ?>

   </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The option I get with this is literally $row[name]

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause, but you need to escape the quotes in the option `echo "<option value=\"$row[name]\"/>";` (or use single quotes, or concatenate instead of interpolate)

Comment: How you are trying to output that is a php syntax for, and the options also just have a value, but no text.

Comment: Name should be like this `$row['name']`

Comment: I have tried single quotes before, I have now moved back to them, but that doesnt solve the problem. The fact that there only is a value and no text doesnt change anything, I think. Qirel, could you elaborate on the first thing you wrote?

Comment: Putting name in single quotes does not help Im afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datalist id has to match the input list attribute and change the loop to `"<option value=" . $row['name'] . "/>"`

Comment: This did not work, Im afraid... The option is still literally $row['name'] and not the content of the database

Comment: @Kriss0612 did you put a dot before and after `$row['name']`?

Comment: Yes, I copied your answer. It did not help :/

Comment: <form>
<input list="chemicals" name="input">
  <datalist id="chemicals">
  
 <?php foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo "<option value=" . $row['name'] . "/>"
  }
  
  ?>
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

Comment: Do you have php installed? try to echo something on top of that,  does it work?

Comment: This was indeed sort of the problem. it was a HTML file, meaning that PHP cannot be used. I have now modified it and made it a PHP file, which has made the script work. Thanks you very much :)